# Can the Python interpreter welcome message be suppressed?

Tags: python

Instead of:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.2 (default, Oct 11 2012, 20:14:37)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

I'd like, for example:

```
$ python --quiet
>>>
```

Comment: FYI, looks like the option may have been added to Python3+ two years ago.  http://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/b7be652daf6e/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$ python -ic ""
>>>
```

Comment: This works by asking Python to interpret (`-c`) an empty string of code, and then drop into interactive mode (`-i`) after that.

Answer (score 6):

Python 3 now has a `-q` flag:

```
python3 -q
```

---

For Python 2, I have a startup file, so this works for me:

```
python2 -i "$PYTHONSTARTUP"
```